# Using JQuery AJAX and php to fetch json object array from a mysql db

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Using JQuery AJAX and php to fetch data from a mysql database there is already an example 
but
I can not figer out how to handle returned object array. 
Following is my json output after executing api.php:

```
[{"timestamp":"12","gas_use":"3000.000","elec_use":"40000.000"},
{"timestamp":"34","gas_use":"4000.000","elec_use":"5000.000"},
{"timestamp":"56","gas_use":"1000.000","elec_use":"2000.000"}]
```

My question is how d I handle the data array in the following client.php

```
$(function () 
  {
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function (data) {
                    },
   }
```

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: handle HOW? for WHAT? you're getting json back, and jquery is decoding that json string into a native javascript object. you'd deal with that like you would any other JS object. just because it came from a webserver as json doesn't mean you have to treat it any differently.

Comment: there are lots and lots of tutorials online for this. Go through them and come back with more specific issues within your code

Answer (score 1):

```
It will work:

var $jsonData = [{"timestamp":"12","gas_use":"3000.000","elec_use":"40000.000"},
{"timestamp":"34","gas_use":"4000.000","elec_use":"5000.000"},
{"timestamp":"56","gas_use":"1000.000","elec_use":"2000.000"}];

$.each( $jsonData, function(key, data){

    // alert(data.timestamp);

    // alert(data.gas_use);
    // alert(data.elec_use);

});
```

Comment: helped me to understand the same problem! great! thank you! +1

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i in data){
    var obj = data[i];
    // obj.timestamp;
    // obj.gas_use;
    // etc
}
```